# How do I get my image info in a DB using Real Ajax Uploader?

Tags: php, ajax, image, upload

I'm using the Real Ajax Uploader

Everything works fine, I can submit an image and it shows up in the example folder. My next goal is to store the image information in a DB so I can display those images on another page. I'm using the instructions [Here](http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader/advanced.php?e=1) but my image info is not hitting the DB, I'm also not getting any error messages.

```
#deny extension by default for security reason
$DENY_EXT = array('php','php3', 'php4', 'php5', 'phtml', 'exe', 'pl', 'cgi', 'html', 'htm', 'js', 'asp', 'aspx', 'bat', 'sh', 'cmd');

function success($file_path)
{
//HERE DEFINE YOUR DB CONNECTION
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "User", "password");
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
$conn->select_db("plainryd");
$id = $conn->query("INSERT INTO uploaded_files(file_name) VALUES($file_path) ");
}
/*
* function that runs on the end, customize here insert to db, or other action todo on the end of upload
* name can be customized
*/
$FINISH_FUNCTION = 'success';
//THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED WHEN THE UPLOAD OF A SINGLE FILE FINISH, HERE CAN BE DONE WHAT ONE NEED
```

My DB is setup with with 3 fields, ID, file_name and file_path

Comment: are you storing a link or the entire image in the db

Comment: I'm just trying to store the file path and the name, the image is stored in a folder. Eventually I'd like to figure out how to tie in the user_name via the session, but that's useless without being able to display the images first

Answer (score 0):

Please Correct the following one it's Works for me

$conn->query("INSERT INTO uploaded_files(file_name) VALUES('$file_path') ");
}